# database search box

Tags: delphi, function

hello i am just new to delphi 7 and i have written a app which manages my mdb database. i just want to put a search box wherein if i put in a keyword it will return results with the keyword on a specific row of the database.

example: on the row named first name i want to search the database with the john keyword then when i hit enter or search button the app will return results with all the data containing john on its first name

```
type
    Tcollector = class(TForm)
    Image1: TImage;
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    ADOTable1: TADOTable;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
    procedure DataSource1DataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  collector: Tcollector;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Tcollector.DataSource1DataChange(Sender: TObject; Field: TField);
begin

end;
```

EDIT:

i have done this:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Grids, DBGrids, DB, ADODB, StdCtrls;

type
    TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ComboBox1: TComboBox;
    ADOConnection1: TADOConnection;
    ADOQuery1: TADOQuery;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    ADOQuery2: TADOQuery;
    ADOQuery3: TADOQuery;
    ADOQuery4: TADOQuery;
    ADOQuery5: TADOQuery;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses Unit2;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
ADOConnection1.GetTableNames(ComboBox1.Items);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var  tblname : string;
begin

if ComboBox1.ItemIndex < 0 then Exit;
tblname := ComboBox1.Items[ComboBox1.ItemIndex];

with ADOQuery1 do begin
Close;
  SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM ' + tblname;
  Open;
end;

with ADOQuery2 do begin
  Close;
  SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM ' + tblname;
  Open;
end;

with ADOQuery3 do begin
  Close;
  SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM ' + tblname;
  Open;
end;

with ADOQuery4 do begin
  Close;
  SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM ' + tblname;
  Open;
end;

with ADOQuery5 do begin
  Close;
  SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM ' + tblname;
  Open;
end;

    end;
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
form2.show;
end;

end.
```

so far i can pull all the table data. what i want my program to do is to display data which i have typed on a tedit

btw sorry for my first post im still not familiar with the forum shortcuts and rules on posting. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TDataSet.Filter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filter)
or
[TDataSet.OnFilterRecord](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.OnFilterRecord)
or use SQL directly.

Comment: thanks for the help.could you give me an idea on what elements to put in the form? example 1 ado connection, 2 label, 1 button, etc...

Comment: btw my database is saved on my pc

Comment: See `Borland\Delphi7\Demos\Db\Filter` demo on the your HD.

Comment: i dont have that folder in my delphy 7 folder

Comment: hello i have done some codes but cant seem to pull out specific data but i can pull out now from tables... cant post code here can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

got it just some minor problems but maybe i can figure it out

```
begin
ADOTable1.First;
if ADOTable1.Locate('Last',edit1.Text ,[]) then begin
Label1.Caption := ADOTable1.FieldByName('Last').AsString;
Label2.Caption := ADOTable1.FieldByName('First').AsString;
Label3.Caption := ADOTable1.FieldByName('address').AsString;
Next;
end else begin
Label1.Caption := '';
Label2.Caption := '';
Label3.Caption := '';
```